# Unable to install php8.2-dev on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, php, perl, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to install `swool` using `perl` on ubuntu server then i get bellow error:

```
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

As i searched turns out i should install `php-dev` but then i got below errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.2-dev : Depends: autoconf (>= 2.63) but it is not installable
              Depends: automake (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
              Depends: shtool but it is not installable
              Depends: libtool (>= 2.4.6-0.1~) but it is not installable
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I can't find any solutions on https://stackoverflow.com or https://askubuntu.com , it would be great If you can help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @karel I used this command `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` and there is no broken package

Answer (score 0):

PHP 8.2 is not in the default Ubuntu 20.04 repos, so you will have to use `ppa:ondrej/php`. You didn't mention if you are using it.

This is what I just tested and it works on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install php8.2-dev
```